# Insert in MySQL from JavaFX

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, javafx-8

Insert in mysql problem from javafx, i keep getting invalid value no matter what i do.  Am trying to have an incrementing value when a button is clicked.  The first value in the database is  Doc -  1 and i want the next value to be Doc -  2 and Doc -  3 in that order. Any help is appreciated particularly in the query as everything is working fine.

```
@FXML
private void GenerateDocTag(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException {

    txtTag.setText( String.valueOf(doctorTag()));

}


private Integer doctorTag() throws SQLException {

    Connection connection = DBController.Connect();

    String query = "\n" +
            "select DocTag from doctors where substring('Doc - 1', -1);";
    resultSet = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
    resultSet.first();
    int DOC_TAG = resultSet.getInt(1);
    return DOC_TAG + 1;
}
```

The error from above is invalid value for getInt()  - 'Doc - 1'

Comment: First check your `substring-value`, `System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1))`, Is output-value int type?

Comment: Do not invoke non-UI code inside the UI thread, this leads to unresponsive apps and unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the below table structure:

```
value
------
Doc - 1
Doc - 2
Doc - 3
```

You need to get the highest value for `value` column and `cast` it into `int` if that's what your `resultSet` expects, e.g."

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(value, -1) AS UNSIGNED) AS VALUE 
FROM test1 ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Another approach would be to get the max `value` and perform `substring` in Java.